# Why can't PIL identify SVG images from stream?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a system that recieves `bytes` object containing an image in format which is not known in advance and is supposed to work with it. I am using `PIL` to do the work for me. [The documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) says that `PIL.Image.open()` can identify the file, even when a file object is passed. I have tried and it works with other file formats. But `SVG` files seem to be problematic.

Is there a way to make `PIL` work by itself or do I have to identify the image by some other means and then force `PIL.Image.open()` to read the image as `SVG`?

MRE:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
import io
import PIL.Image

with requests.get("https://github.githubassets.com/favicons/favicon.svg") as r:
    data = r.content

with io.BytesIO(data) as image:
    PIL.Image.open(image)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MRE.py", line 11, in <module>
    PIL.Image.open(image)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3283, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fe38b2457b0>
```

Comment: [PIL doesn't support SVG images](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html) since they are vectors and rendering them basically requires a entire HTML parser and renderer

Comment: PIL works with rasterized images. SVGs are vector graphics - it's not surprising that it can't identify the format. Even if you could open it, how exactly do you expect to manipulate an SVG via PIL? It's sort of like trying to open a PDF document in Microsoft Word, and expecting to be able to edit the PDF because PDFs and Word files sort of fall into the same category of "documents with text inside of them."

Comment: PIL can actually read EPS files which are also vectors but are much easier to parse and vectorize

Comment: To give some idea of the difficulties of SVG handling, it is possible to implement an [entire playable Tetris game](https://www.xul.fr/svgtetris.svg) as an SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pillow/PIL does not support SVG input.

You need to render to a raster graphic first if you want to process SVG input with PIL. This can be done, e.g., using *CairoSVG* module.

There is no good support for editing SVG graphics directly in Python. It can be done, however, by editing the underlying XML structure using *lxml* module.

Comment: Is there anyway of editing an SVG, without being "editing the underlying XML structure", except by using a visual app?  In any language? I mean -- SVG is XML. The only "pixels" that can be there are in an embedded escaped raster image.

Comment: Yes, there are libraries to create/manipulate SVG or other vector graphics. It is simply much more convenient to have a proper graphics object model instead of hacking around in tags and attributes. Examples: https://docs.rs/svg/latest/svg/ https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvggenerator.html https://svgjs.dev/ https://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/ https://github.com/ajstarks/svgo I used lxml myself to edit an SVG, only simple operations, and it was not much fun.